Regarding the Boundary of Bounded Non-empty Open Sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$
I tend to imagine bounded open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as collections of nice slightly punctured blobs so I came up with these questions to check whether my biases are actually correct. If $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set,

Does there always exist $U\subseteq\partial A$ open in the subspace topology such that $U\cong\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?
Does there always exist an embedding $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\hookrightarrow\partial A$?
Is $\text{ind}(\partial A)=n-1$ always true? Here, $\text{ind}(\cdot)$ is the inductive dimension.

These questions are ordered so that $1\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 3$. If 1 is true, my intuitions are actually correct. If 3 is false, my intuitions fail miserably. Note that the boundedness condition is key since, for example, $A=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ is such that $\partial A=\{0\}$ which doesn't satisfy any of these expected properties.

If $C\subset[0,1]$ is the standard Cantor set, I feel like $A=[0,1]\setminus C$ fails #1 when $n=1$, which would lead to refutations for higher $n$ as well. Can someone with more expertise comment? (tbh I thought this would refute #3 as well, but it definitely doesn't refute #2 which would violate the given implications)

3 is a duplicate of this. For 1 and 2 the answer is negative, one can take for instance a circle of pseudoarcs in the plane and the domain it bounds.
